# dhtmlx schedulerでWHERE句が効かない

Tags: php

週間スケジュールを作成する際に、週が変わるたびにその週の情報を取得したいので
render_sql関数を使って、条件指定を行おうと思いましたが、論理削除フラグ(del_flg)の条件さえも適用されません。

：環境

- CakePHP 1.2
- MySQL 5.5.16
- PHP 5.3.8
- dhtmlx 3.0

：ソースコード

```
    $connector = new SchedulerConnector($this->TEventSchedule, "PHPCake");
    $connector->render_sql("SELECT id, start_date,end_date,event_name FROM t_event_schedules WHERE del_flg = 0","id","start_date,end_date,event_name");
```

何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授願います。

Comment: 本題と関係ないですが、削除フラグを用いて実際にはデータを消さず、削除したことにするのは「論理削除」です。

Comment: dhtmlxのバージョンも記載しておくとよいかもしれません。

Comment: @quesera2 ありがとうございます。書き間違えておりました。訂正します。

Comment: @nojimage ありがとうございます。追記しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

ソースをざっと追ったところ、WHERE句をセットするコードが見当たらなかったので、
DBDataWrapperクラスのselectメソッド(db_common.php)を参考に、
PHPCakeDBDataWrapperクラスのselectメソッド(db_phpcake.php)を下記のように書き換えました。（オーバーライドする形や、別ファイルにする形にしようか考え中です）

```
class PHPCakeDBDataWrapper extends ArrayDBDataWrapper{
    public function select($source){
        $select=$source->get_fieldset();
        if (!$select){
            $select=$this->config->db_names_list($this);
            $select = implode(",",$select);
        }

        $where=$this->build_where($source->get_filters(),$source->get_relation());
        $sort=$this->build_order($source->get_sort_by());

        $res = $this->connection->query($this->select_query($select,$source->get_source(),$where,$sort,$source->get_start(),$source->get_count()));
        if (sizeof($res)){
            $nameCamer = get_class($this->connection);
            $name = Inflector::underscore($nameCamer) . "s";
            $temp = array();
            for ($i=sizeof($res)-1; $i>=0; $i--)
                $temp[]=&$res[$i][$name];
        }
        return new ArrayQueryWrapper($temp);
    }
```

ひとまず、この方法で進めてみます。